# Image gallery with rating system

Tags: gallery, system, rating

I am looking to create an image gallery with a rating system built in for the photos. I am using a wordpress right now and it doesn't have ratings, nor does the wordpress automatically pull from the directory when I upload new photos.

Basically what I am trying to do it upload a ton of a photos in bulk to a folder such as /img/ and the site will automatically pick up the new photos, and allow users to rate them instantly.

Any suggestions on what I should use that is free and can be built on?

I am looking to get away from Wordpress..

Answer (score 0):

[PhotoSmash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/), although development appears to have stopped, has image/image galleries with "star ratings".

Comment: Does this pull automatically from a directory?

Comment: Yeah. I want to get away from wordpress i think

Comment: Then you'll need to write some code and come back when you've got something.

Comment: if you noticed the question, I was asking for suggestions not for a smart ass remark.

Comment: I have read the question and it doesn't show much research. You haven't found *anything* similar? I did one search and came up with a plugin that satisfies on of your criteria, you could build upon that for starters.

Comment: It doesn't show any research because I didn't put "well, i looked here and looked at this website and searched this"? I will include sources for you like high school if you'd like. I didn't find anything or else I wouldn't waste my time asking people on here that do this for a living and know exactly what to look for. Thanks for your input Alex.